# 'Javac' is not recognized error in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, I downloaded and installed Intellij in my Windows machine. However, while trying to set the PATH, I saw that I did not have `jdk`, I only had `jre`. So, then I downloaded `jdk 1.8` and set the PATH as instructed through adding PATH in the Environment variables. Now although `javac` command is being recognized in command prompt, however, the terminal inside Intellij still shows -- 'javac' is not a recognized internal or external command. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: did you try to restart the IDE? did you update also the JAVA_HOME path? Some other solution might be to setup SDK in IntelliJ.

Comment: Does the reboot help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Go to File -> Project Structure. Is the project SDK set to the JDK path? If not, set the path to the jdk 1.8 folder
2. Have you rebooted Intellij after setting up the path? If not, restart Intellij
3. In the intellij console, check what the JAVA_HOME variable is set to

Answer (score 1):

Test it in your `CMD`. If that works, reboot the computer. Intellij IDEA is having trouble sometimes with reloading the environment variables.